# How to solve this problem, im using Symfony 3.1

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

```
composer require symfonycasts/reset-password-bundle
```

print this

**Problem 1
- symfonycasts/reset-password-bundle[v1.9.0, ..., v1.9.1] require symfony/config ^4.4 | ^5.0 -> found symfony/config[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.26, v5.0.0, ..., v5.3.3] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- Root composer.json requires symfonycasts/reset-password-bundle ^1.9 -> satisfiable by symfonycasts/reset-password-bundle[v1.9.0, v1.9.1].**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see on the [packagist page of that package](https://packagist.org/packages/symfonycasts/reset-password-bundle), there is no  version of that bundle that is compatible with a Symfony version older than 4.4. And as Symfony 3.1 is [out of support](https://symfony.com/releases/3.1) for four years now, you should plan to update it anyways

Comment: OK, Thanks, sorry for the question so i'm a new programmer and new at Symfony but, your response is okey, Thanks again.